# How to disable and re enable the click functionality of a div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

For this question there are some other related questions which explains the possibility of the re enabling of `input field` or `button` using `disabled` attribute.

But my requirement is for re-enablebing the div click functionality after some action. Currently I'm using `.off()` for disabling the click function of a div after first click.

But I'm not able to re-enable it back.

**Code where div is disabled**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // Will ask for city through voice when user click on the instruction box.
        var accessBtn = $('#skitt-listening-box');
        $("#skitt-listening-box").click(function(){
          $(this).off('click'); // code to disble div from click
          //some functionality
        });

  });
```

**Code where div is enabled:**

```
if(IsEmail($(".voice_email").val())) {
              //some functionality
              //Should re-enable the div to click here              
          });
```

Comment: how about adding some code

Comment: Sounds like you need `on()` and `toggleclass()`?

Comment: sure, @RST I will do it now.

Comment: @RST can you please help me now?

Comment: I think it is best to use `.prop("disabled",true)/.prop("disabled",false)` to disable/enable the button. Your `if(IsEmail(...))` should be in an eventhandler though otherwise it will not run.

Comment: Well, thanks for that @RST I actually tried it. But the problem is the 'disabled' attribute doesn't support for div's.
Got to know about this after a long search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you i try adding css classes to describe state.

In your way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Will ask for city through voice when user click on the instruction box.
    var $accessBtn = $('#skitt-listening-box');
    $accessBtn.click(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass('click-available'){
         //do action
         $(this).removeClass('click-available');
       }
    });
});
```

And to enable click:

```
if(IsEmail($(".voice_email").val())) {
    $accessBtn.addClass('click-available');            
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for that little hack @manveru ,
it worked like a pro :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
function addClickFunctionality() {
  $("#skitt-listening-box").on('click', function(){
    $(this).off('click'); // code to disable div from click
    // some functionality
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Will ask for city through voice when user click on the instruction box.
  addClickFunctionality();
});


// re-enable click handle in some action
if(IsEmail($(".voice_email").val())) {
  // some functionality
  addClickFunctionality();              
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by addClickFunctionality();

Can you make it more clear?